# Photo slider in ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

Can you suggest a best library available for photo slider ?

I am getting 400+ photos live url.

Currently i am displaying in uicollectionview.

When user select 150 at row only one photos should be load and open full size. IN that full side next and previous button must be there so user navigate to next photo.

So pls tell me best library name.

Reference . https://github.com/NYTimes/NYTPhotoViewer

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats wrong with collection view ?

Comment: Nothing Wrong. But I want extra slider in after selecting particular image

Comment: I've used this one, it's a really powerful library for photo gallery, also has video support: https://github.com/mariohahn/MHVideoPhotoGallery

Comment: on did select item, u go to detail view with one imageview, there u can use buttons to show the next image on the same imageview with some animation!!!

Comment: Can you suggest custom library..

Comment: FabKremer How to use collection view did select ? My apps is crashing